# UWP MapControl issue anchoring xaml children

Tags: xaml, uwp, uwp-xaml, uwp-maps

I'm new to UWP MapControl currently. I have a simple problem when adding XAML children to map (instead of the regular map elements).

this is my code:

```
    private void MapRightTapped(MapControl sender, MapRightTappedEventArgs args)
    {
        Ellipse circle = new Ellipse() { Height = 20, Width = 20, Fill = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black)};
        sender.Children.Add(circle);

        Geopoint position = new Geopoint(new BasicGeoposition()
        {
            Latitude = args.Location.Position.Latitude,
            Longitude = args.Location.Position.Longitude,
            Altitude = 5000,

        });
        MapControl.SetLocation(circle, position);
        MapControl.SetNormalizedAnchorPoint(circle, new Point(0.5, 0.5));
     }
```

At first the point displayed correctly on the map.
**but after zooming or tilting the map, 
the circle appeared to be anchored at the surface altitude and NOT at altitude of 5000**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set an altitude reference system. Leaving it set to the default of unspecified will cause the altitude value to be ignored.

Comment: i tried all altitude reference system in the enum the same behavior :/, further more even when adding MapIcon where you can't set this property the same behavior occurred.

Comment: Altitude is supported for both XAML children and MapIcons, but will only work in Road mode on Creator's Update. It works in Aerial mode on all Windows 10 versions.

Comment: For XAML you would do this:             Ellipse circle = new Ellipse() { Height = 20, Width = 20, Fill = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black) };
            MyMapControl.Children.Add(circle);

            Geopoint position = new Geopoint(new BasicGeoposition()
            {
                Latitude = 47.2,
                Longitude = -121.8,
                Altitude = 10000,

            }, AltitudeReferenceSystem.Ellipsoid);
            MapControl.SetLocation(circle, position);
            MapControl.SetNormalizedAnchorPoint(circle, new Point(0.5, 0.5));

Comment: MapIcon you would do this:             var poiLocation = new Geopoint(new BasicGeoposition
            {
                Latitude = 47.643496,
                Longitude = -122.138343,
                Altitude = 5000
            },
            AltitudeReferenceSystem.Surface);

            this.myMapIcon = new MapIcon
            {
                Location = poiLocation,
            };

            this.MyMapControl.MapElements.Add(this.myMapIcon);